# Match regular expression to next special character while allowing spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using Javascript to extract parts of a string using a regex.

I have a string like:

```
lorem ipsum !bang #hash #hash2 ^caret word @at sym
```

I am trying to pull out the words beginning with the various characters - sometimes they can have a space in them, and there can be multiple of each type. So I want to convert this string to a set of values such as:

```
text: "lorem ipsum"
!: "bang"
#: ["hash", "hash2"]
^: "caret word"
@: "at sym"
```

My current regex is `/ ([!#^@>\/*-]\w+)/gm`. This sort of works, but it does not match spaces - so from the sample above it only produces `caret` for `^`, and not the whole `caret word`.

My code to do this is:

```
var result = {};

var re = / ([!#^@>\/*-]\w+)/gm;
var m;

var firstSpecialCharIndex = inputString.search(/ [!#^@>\/*-]/);
result["text"] = inputString.substring(0, firstSpecialCharIndex);

while ((m = re.exec(inputString)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
    re.lastIndex++;
  }

  var index = m[1].substring(0,1);
  if(result[index] == null)
    result[index] = [];
  result[index].push(m[1].substring(1));
}
```

Does anyone know how I can match up to the next special character, including the space between multiple words (but not the space after it to the next special char)? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am removing `text` part for simplicity. You can use lookahead

```
([!#^@>\/*-])(.*?)(?=\s[!#^@>\/*-]|$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oA1bK7/2)**

Group 1 contains symbol and group 2 contains text and you can trim the result if you want.

*JS Demo*

```js
var inputString = "lorem ipsum !bang #hash #hash2 ^caret word @at sym";

var result = {};

var re = /([!#^@>\/*-])(.*?)(?=\s[!#^@>\/*-]|$)/gm;
var m;

var firstSpecialCharIndex = inputString.search(/ [!#^@>\/*-]/);
result["text"] = inputString.substring(0, firstSpecialCharIndex);

while ((m = re.exec(inputString)) !== null) {
    var index = m[1];
    if(result[index] == null) {
        result[index] = [];
    }
    result[index].push(m[2].trim());
}
document.writeln("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer that worked. It works perfectly with multiple words/numbers/special characters. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/ ((?:[!#^@>\/*-]\w+)(?: [^!#^@>\/*-]\w+)*)/gm
```

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/iW5pY6/2)

`?:` in the parenthesis makes so subpattern does not do any capturing. remove it and look what's changed.

Tested this code in the `Chrome`:

```
var inputString = "lorem ipsum !bang #hash #hash2 ^long caret word @at sym";

var result = {};

//var re = / ([!#^@>\/*-]\w+)/gm;
var re = / ((?:[!#^@>\/*-]\w+)(?: [^!#^@>\/*-]\w+)*)/gm;
var m;

var firstSpecialCharIndex = inputString.search(/ [!#^@>\/*-]/);
result["text"] = inputString.substring(0, firstSpecialCharIndex);

while ((m = re.exec(inputString)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }

    var index = m[1].substring(0,1);
    if(result[index] == null) {
        result[index] = [];
    }
    result[index].push(m[1].substring(1));
}
console.log(result);
```

it works well.

Comment: Thank you, this very nearly works, but it only matches two words - sometimes there can be multiple words before the next special char. Do you know of a way that last group can essentially be made to repeat itself for unlimited words? Thanks

Comment: @samiles, nope, it matches multiple words too, see `https://regex101.com/r/iW5pY6/3` try change `TEST STRING` and check the results

Comment: in my regex look at the `(?: [^!#^@>\/*-]\w+)*`, there is a `*` sign after parenthesis. It means exactly what you need.

Comment: OK, that's odd. It's not working in my code - must be something in my JS or whatever if the regex is right. Thank you I will keep trying.

Comment: @samiles, you meen it's not working in your code from your question?

Comment: Ah, you're right in that it works with `many multiple words` but fails in my tests with something like `multiple 3 words` - it stops at the 3. I will try to work around this unless you know how to match numbers too? I should have specified it is any alphanumeric digit or space, except the special character set.

Comment: It also interprets `#ha/sh` as `ha` and not `ha/sh` - special characters should only be captured when preceded by a space.

Comment: The regex in rock321987's answer solved these problems. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion for an alternative, but if a regex is used to split on the specialchars (preceding with a non capturing space and lookahead alphanumeric char), while keeping the captured special char, the logic could be rewritten to:

```js
var inputString = 'lorem ipsum !bang #hash #hash2 ^caret word @at sym'

var rx = /(?:\s)([!#^@>\/*-](?=\w))/;
var arr = inputString.split(rx);
var result = {text:  arr[0]};
for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
  var ind = arr[i++], val = arr[i];
    var coll = (result[ind] = result[ind] || []);
    coll.push(val);    
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

The main advantage is that the special chars are not repeated in the expression. A small secondary one is that the search is executed only once (the 'text' part is simply the first element in the results).
It will also work with multiple words and/or special chars in the middle of a word such as `'lorem ipsum !bang #ha/sh adfa #ha3sh2 ^caret word asdf @at sym'`